# extjs6 chart, create multiple lines dynamically

Tags: extjs, charts

I'm stuck on something very simple with my ExtJs6 line chart.  I am trying to draw 2 difference series separated by Instrument.  If you look at my data below there should be 2 lines, 1 for crudeOil and 1 for gold.  I want the date at the bottom of the chart, and the CumulativePl along the left Y axis.

I can't figure out how to add these dynamically to my chart.  Any help is much appreciated!  I was able to put pl on the yaxis and filedate on xaxis, but its in 1 line and not separated by instrument.

Here is my store with data.

```
    store1.add({
        Filedate: '2018-08-10',
        Instrument: 'crudeOil',
        CumulativePl: 999
    });

    store1.add({
        Filedate: '2018-08-11',
        Instrument: 'crudeOil',
        CumulativePl: 1200
    });

    store1.add({
        Filedate: '2018-08-10',
        Instrument: 'gold',
        CumulativePl: 500
    });

    store1.add({
        Filedate: '2018-08-11',
        Instrument: 'gold',
        CumulativePl: 700
    });
```

UPDATE... based on responses I need to make a store for each line series I want to graph.  So now I am grouping my store by instrument and I will need to create a new store for each instrument in the store which I am confused on how to do.
//group store, for each group

```
    myStore.group('instrument');
    myStore.getGroups().each(function (group, i) {

        debugger;
        //create store here

        group.each(function (record) {
            //foreach item in group, populate store
            debugger;
        });

        //create series of data from newly created store
        //add series to chart
    });

enter code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create two separated stores for each series, like this:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        var me = this;

        var storeOil = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: [{
                name: 'Filedate',
                type: 'date',
                dateFormat: 'Y-m-d'
            }, {
                name: 'Instrument',
                type: 'string'
            },
            {
                name: 'CumulativePl',
                type: 'float'
            }],
            data: [{
                "Filedate": '2018-08-10',
                "Instrument": 'crudeOil',
                "CumulativePl": 999
            }, {
                "Filedate": '2018-08-11',
                "Instrument": 'crudeOil',
                "CumulativePl": 1200
            }]
        });

        var storeGold = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: [{
                name: 'Filedate',
                type: 'date',
                dateFormat: 'Y-m-d'
            }, {
                name: 'Instrument',
                type: 'string'
            },
            {
                name: 'CumulativePl',
                type: 'float'
            }],
            data: [{
                "Filedate": '2018-08-10',
                "Instrument": 'gold',
                "CumulativePl": 500
            }, {
                "Filedate": '2018-08-11',
                "Instrument": 'gold',
                "CumulativePl": 700
            }]
        });



        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'Hello',
            width: '100%',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'cartesian',
                width: '100%',
                height: 500,

                insetPadding: 40,
                innerPadding: {
                    left: 40,
                    right: 40
                },
                axes: [{
                    type: 'numeric',
                    fields: 'CumulativePl',
                    position: 'left',
                    grid: true,
                    minimum: 0
                }, {
                    type: 'time',
                    fields: 'Filedate',
                    position: 'bottom',
                    grid: true,
                    label: {
                        rotate: {
                            degrees: -40
                        }
                    }
                }],
                series: [{
                    type: 'line',
                    store: storeGold,
                    xField: 'Filedate',
                    yField: 'CumulativePl'

                },{
                    type: 'line',
                    store: storeOil,
                    xField: 'Filedate',
                    yField: 'CumulativePl'


                }]
            }]
        });
    }
});
```